# What should our tour's question and answers look like?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, introductory-tour

The [tour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site is relatively high-traffic page for newcomers, and one of the ways we can optimize it is by choosing the question and answers that appear on it.  However, there are very strict limitations on what can appear – in fact, only one question on this entire site is currently eligible.

See [What determines the questions available for selection in the tour page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163947/300411) for details on these criteria and [this SEDE query for eligible and almost eligible questions on our site](https://data.stackexchange.com/latin/query/473660/possible-tour-questions-and-near-misses), but the most important points are an upvoted question with at least two upvoted answers, and all three having fewer than 400 characters each and no special formatting.

The question we are currently using isn't great for a few reasons, perhaps most crucially because it is a popular question that is frequently modified and thus can be made suddenly ineligible for the tour.  A more stable solution is to artificially set up a question and answers and then lock it once it meets the criteria.

So this is your opportunity to make suggestions regarding the content that should appear in the tour.  Feel free to invent something completely new, or to cut down an existing question/answer.

We'll then conscript a few users and coordinate the asking, answering, and voting of the highest-voted suggestion, and once it's in place, a moderator will lock the post so that we have a nice-looking tour in perpetuity.

All that said – please post suggestions here with one set per answer. We need a:

```
# Question title

Question body

[tags]

* Good answer one

* Good answer two
```

To reiterate: The question and answer bodies need to each be 400 characters or less (which is counted according to the generated HTML, probably also including the surrounding `<p><p/>`) and may not contain any special block level formatting such as headers, block-quotes, or lists.

Comment: For the record: we have created the example question as suggested below by Joonas: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7526/why-is-there-a-q-in-spqr

Comment: Thanks for everyone's assistance!  The [tour] has been updated.

Answer (score 5):

## Why is there a Q in SPQR?

The abbreviation SPQR stands for *Senatus PopulusQue Romanus*. Why is the Q included, as there are only three words? Why isn't it just SPR? Or does SPQR stand for something else?

[abbreviations](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abbreviations) [conjunction](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjunction)

- The enclitic *-que* was treated much like a word. This is most evident in the way Ovid handles quotes, where *-que* is outside a quote but the word it's attached to is inside. There are few other ancient abbreviations with *-que*, if any, so it's difficult to compare.

  - Comment to this answer: For a concrete example, consider *Metamorphoses* V.414: "*adgnovitque deam 'ne' c 'longius ibitis!' inquit*" which uses *-c* instead of *-que*.
- We definitely know that SPQR refers to *senatus populusque Romanus* and not something else. This text is inscribed in full in the temple of Saturn and arch of Titus in Rome. It's hard to say whether the abbreviation is systematic or an arbitrary choice that happened to stick.

Comment: This is based on [this actual question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5045/79), condensed here to fit the tour. Any suggestions for improvements here or other options are welcome!

Comment: How about something more definitive for the last sentence of the first answer, like "There are few other ancient abbreviations with *-que*, if any, so it's difficult to compare."

Comment: @Nathaniel Good idea! I elaborated on the second one a little more, too. I feel a little uneasy about referring to Ovid without giving specific examples, but there isn't much room.

Comment: This looks good!

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I think that not providing any explicit examples could be useful; it would allow for a good example comment like *"Are there any specific examples from Ovid which might demonstrate this?"*

Comment: @EthanBierlein Or better yet, the comment could point out a specific passage in Ovid. I actually think such a comment would work nicely for the tour.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Agreed!